# Non-unique constraint names applying across tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, constraints

Through SQLAlchemy and Alembic I created some table constraints that share a name but are otherwise independent. This generates some surprising results where the constraint checks were applied to columns in tables that do not match the constraint specification.

Reproducible example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    join_date DATE,
    userrole VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT role CHECK (userrole IN ('standard', 'admin', 'readonly'))
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS groups;

CREATE TABLE groups (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    grouprole VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT role CHECK (grouprole IN ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))
);
```

The check in the `users` table applies a constraint to columns in both the `users` table *and* in the `groups` table. Similarly, the check in the `groups` table applies a constraint to columns in the `groups` table *and* the `users` table.

Where the check crosses between tables, it's applied to the column at the index where you'd expect it to be applied in the table that defines it. The example above results in this:

Users:

| column | name | type | nullable | check | default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id | uuid | NO | NULL | uuid_generate_v4() |
| 2 | created_at | timestamp | NO | (role)::text = ANY ((ARRAY['foo'::character varying, 'bar'::character varying, 'baz'::character varying])::text[]) | NULL |
| 3 | updated_at | timestamp | NO | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | join_date | date | YES | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | userrole | varchar(19) | NO | (role)::text = ANY ((ARRAY['standard'::character varying, 'admin'::character varying, 'readonly'::character varying])::text[]) | NULL |
| 6 | status | varchar(24) | NO | NULL | NULL |

Groups:

| column | name | type | nullable | check | default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id | uuid | NO | NULL | uuid_generate_v4() |
| 2 | grouprole | varchar(19) | NO | (role)::text = ANY ((ARRAY['foo'::character varying, 'bar'::character varying, 'baz'::character varying])::text[]) | NULL |
| 3 | created_at | timestamp | NO | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | updated_at | timestamp | NO | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | status | varchar(24) | NO | (role)::text = ANY ((ARRAY['standard'::character varying, 'admin'::character varying, 'readonly'::character varying])::text[]) | NULL |

Changing the name of one of the constraints is sufficient to fix this problem. Is this the way constraints are supposed to work?

I created a [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=786d838751779d5ec08f6ea2a3df3df1) that shows it applies across multiple versions of Postgres.

Comment: You've missed `ccu.table_name = cls.relname` condition for `constraint_column_usage` join, so you join constrain by name and schema only. Given two constraints with the name you get them twice. If you check schema with `\d+`  in psql there's no issue.

Comment: The tables I've posted there are straight out of the "structure" tab in my database UI tool (TablePlus). I just checked, and indeed the check is not enforced! So this looks to be a bug in that tool. Thank you!